# Tomcat not running on Mac OS X

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, pentaho, mondrian

I'm trying to run Tomcat on Mac OS X (leopard) according to the directions on this article:

http://computersight.com/software/how-to-install-mondrian-the-complete-guide/

I was able to run ./startup.sh properly and see the screen in step#3 at one point, but after I got through all 16 steps, I was longer able to view that same screen at localhost:8080.  I followed the instructions closely.  The only thing I changed different was in step #15, I changed jdbcUser and jdbcPassword for the following files: (arrows.jsp, colors.jsp, fourhier.jsp, mondrian.jsp).  I changed those to root user.

Java and Mysql are installed and functioning properly; I'm just trying to get Tomcat to run properly.  Any help or advice to get me looking in the right direction would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What error/output are you getting (either in the console when you run `startup.sh`, or in the browser when you try to connect)?

Answer (score 3):

Do you have Homebrew?

paste this into your shell to install homebrew

`/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/gist/323731)"`

Then try

`brew search tomcat`

to run

`catalina run`

see this

http://www.railscoder.com/installing-tomcat-with-homebrew-on-osx/

Answer (score 1):

This is a good article take about

```
 brew install tomcat
```

https://maltronic.io/2016/01/14/easily-install-apache-tomcat-on-mac-os-x-10-11-el-capitan-with-homebrew/